Swift Package Manager .package(name: , url:) deprecated
I get a warning while building my swift package.
I have Package.swift:
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Lottie", url: "https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-spm.git", from: "4.5.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: ["Lottie"]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackage Tests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)

And I get warning:
'package(name:url:from:)' is deprecated: use package(url:from:) instead

But if I use package(url:from:), like:
.package(url: "https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-spm.git", from: "4.5.0")

I get error:
product 'Lottie' required by package 'mypackage' target 'MyPackage' not found. Did you mean 'Lottie'?

How it can be resolved in right way?

You need to add the dependency like this:
...
 dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Lottie", url: "https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-spm.git", from: "4.5.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
               .product(name: "Lottie", package: "lottie-spm"), // <<<< HERE
             ],
...


NOT like this:
dependencies: ["Lottie"],


You are welcome, can you accept it then?
